# Using Doctrine's EntityManager in a repository design

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, repository-pattern

I'm trying to implement a repository pattern in my zend framework 2 application. I have made a service

```
<?php
class UserService {

private $userRepository;
public function __construct(IUserRepository $repo) {
    $this -> userRepository = $repo;
}

public function createUser($params) {
    $this -> userRepository -> create($params);
}

public function findAllUsers() {
    return $this -> userRepository -> getAllUsers();
}
}
```

which has a repository that implements an interface

```
class UserRepository implements IUserRepository {

public function getAllUsers() {
    //return all users
}

public function getUserById($id) {

}
public function getOneUser($params){

}
public function getUsers($params){

}
public function create($params){

}
public function update($params){

}
public function delete($params){

}
}


<?php
interface IUserRepository {

public function getAllUsers();
public function getUserById($id);
public function getOneUser($params);
public function getUsers($params);
public function create($params);
public function update($params);
public function delete($params);

}
```

In my module.php I make use of dependency injection to determine which repository I inject into a controller

```
public function getControllerConfig() {
    return array('factories' => array(
        'My\Controller\Accounts' => function(){
            return new AccountsController(new UserRepository());
        }, 
    ), 
    );
}
```

In my controller I pass the repository to my service

```
class AccountsController extends AbstractActionController {

private $service;
public function __construct(IUserRepository $repo) {
    $this->service = new UserService($repo);
}
public function indexAction() {
    $all_users = $this->service->findAllUsers();
    return new ViewModel(array('users' => $all_users));
}
}
```

My problem is that I'm using Doctrine as Orm and I want to use the entitymanager in my repositories but I don't know how to do that, any ideas and feedback are appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this, of course.  The typical way you'd do this kind of thing in a ZF2/D2 project would be to start with [DoctrineORMModule](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule).

That module exposes Doctrine's EntityManager via the ZF2 Service Manager in a variety of handy ways (you can $sm->get('doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default') to explicitly get the EM instance).

Once you can get your entitymanager from the SM, you write a factory for your repository, and inject the EM.

---

That said, there's a cleaner way.  Doctrine has built-in support for repositories, and you can [extend the default implementation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#custom-repositories).

Your repository would then look like this:

```
<?php
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class UserRepository extends EntityRepository implements IUserRepository {


public function getAllUsers() {
    return $this->findAll();
}

// ...
}
```

Just remember to add the repository class to the User Entity's metadata.  For example, with an annotation:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyDomain\Model\UserRepository")
 */
class User
{

}
```

Comment: If I extend from an Entityrepository wouldn't I have to do something like $users = $em->getRepository('My\Model\User')->getAllUsers(); in my service class?  I want my service class to not know what kind of implementation it uses to get data from my database.

Comment: @DannyBiezen - not really.  You can just limit your service class to using the methods defined in your IUserRepository interface.  The fact that you leverage EntityRepository to implement that interface is just an implementation detail.